# Gradle 5: Failed to apply plugin [id 'aspectj']

Tags: spring, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to run a build.gradle file that looks like this and which returns an error on line *apply plugin: 'aspectj'*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/release" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
        maven { url "https://maven.eveoh.nl/content/repositories/releases" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "nl.eveoh:gradle-aspectj:2.0"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'aspectj'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Created-By": "Iuliana Cosmina",
                "Specification-Title": "Pro Spring 5",
                "Main-Class": "com.apress.prospring5.ch5.AspectJDemo",
                "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
        )
    }
}
```

The error message is as follows:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/me/Spring/pro-spring-5-master/chapter05/aspectj-aspects/build.gradle' line: 17

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':chapter05:aspectj-aspects'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'aspectj']
   > Could not find method deleteAllActions() for arguments [] on task ':chapter05:aspectj-aspects:compileJava' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue and published a new version to jcenter. Find it here: https://bintray.com/zebalu/releases/gradle-aspectj

currently you need this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath 'io.github.zebalu:gradle-aspectj:2.3.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'gradle-aspectj'
// rest of your code
```

Answer (score 1):

AspectJ is not compatible with Gradle 5.0 - see issues [#7861](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7861) and [#8063](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8063).

The most easy might be to [replace the plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=aspectj); eg. with `io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving`, because `aspectj.gradle` had been last updated 2 years ago (it seems abandoned).